# C# UWP How can I change foreground of TextBox

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I change foreground of TextBox if text is changed?
For example, I will write "zzz" and foreground will be change on "Red".

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
        <TextBox Width="200" Text="asdasd" x:Name="qwerty">

        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add `Foreground` and `TextChanged` to TextBox:

```
<TextBox Foreground="{DynamicResource txtColor}" Width="200" Text="asdasd" x:Name="qwerty" TextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged">

</TextBox>
```

Then you can change foreground of textbox dynamically in TextChanged event as following:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if(textBox.Text == "zzz")
    {
        Application.Current.Resources["txtColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do it without any events? Only with xaml.

Comment: As far as I know you can not detect change textbox without using event.

Comment: @Chips does my answer help you?

Comment: Yes your answer helped me, thank you. But I want to know how can I do it by xaml. I thinking that need use VisualState